# Formview insertion not firing the insert method

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm using formview in order to edit an entity model. The simplified formview header code is:

```
<asp:FormView ID="formViewSalon" runat="server" DataSourceID="OdsSalonData">
```

The object data source code is:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OdsSalonData" runat="server"  
                      DataObjectTypeName="WebApplication1.EDM.Salon" 
                      DeleteMethod="DeleteSalon" InsertMethod="CreateNewSalon"
                      SelectMethod="GetSalonBySalonId" 
                      TypeName="WebApplication1.EDM.SalonLogic" 
                      UpdateMethod="UpdateSalon" OnSelecting="OdsSalonData_Selecting">
```

The code for the Save/update button is:

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (formViewSalon.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
    {
        formViewSalon.InsertItem(true);
    }
    else if (formViewSalon.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        formViewSalon.UpdateItem(true);
    }
}
```

When I'm updating the form, the method `UpdateSalon` fires when trying to execute the line:

```
formViewSalon.UpdateItem(true);
```

but when I try to insert a new record, the method `CreateNewSalon` is not firing while running:

```
formViewSalon.InsertItem(true);
```

The definitions for the 2 methods are:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
public string CreateNewSalon(Salon newSalon) { }
```

and:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Update, true)]
public void UpdateSalon(Salon updatedSalon) { }
```

I'm going crazy where's the difference between the 2 processes.
Please advise, any clue/idea would be immediately tested! thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `FormViewSalon_ItemInserting` method?

Comment: @nemesv I think it's not relevant since I've removed it completely and the behavior remains the same. I edited the question accordingly.